# reference a function from within another function

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if I am doing this right.

```
var pagefunction = function() {

    anotherfunction(){
        alert("it worked");
    }
}

pagefunction.anotherfunction();
```

Basically I am trying to call a function inside another function, would anyone be able to advise what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pagefunction = {
    anotherfunction:function(){
        alert("it worked");
    }
}
pagefunction.anotherfunction();
```

For more details visit http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/

Comment: +1 (+ more if I could) I never thought about that method! Awesome job!

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
var pagefunction = function() {
    return function(){
        alert("it worked");
    };
};
```

To invoke:

```
pagefunction()();
```

OR:

```
var fn = pagefunction();
fn();
```

Comment: +1 because this is super neat, but please realize that the techniques used here (closures & functional programming) are a bit hard to wrap your head around at first, so don't get too confused. Just look up those as search terms and you'll get it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a basic syntax error.

You're calling `anotherfunction` but then adding a body like you're trying to declare it or something. You can't do that. This is what it should look like:

```
var anotherfunction = function() {
    alert("It Worked!");
}

var pagefunction = function() {
    anotherfunction();
 }

pagefunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

To call a function, you just write the function name followed by parentheses, with parameters inside the parentheses. You don't put `{ ... }` after it, that's for defining a function.

```
var pagefunction = function() {
    anotherfunction(); // Call the other function
    alert("it worked!"); // Alert after the other functioin returns
}
```

You call this as just:

```
pagefunction();
```

In order to use:

```
pagefunction.anotherfunction();
```

`pagefunction` would have to be an object, not a function. That object would have a property named  `anotherfunction` that contains a function.

Or if you wanted to write:

```
pagefunction().anotherfunction();
```

`pagefunction` would have to be a function that returns an object, and that object would have to have a property named `anotherfunction` that contains a function.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like below.

```
var pagefunction = (function () {
    return new function () {
        var that = this;
        that.another = function () {
            alert("it worked");
        };
    };
})();
```